Unable to import PyTorch in Jetson nano
I have trouble importing PyTorch in my jetson nano (jetpack 4.4).I have successfully installed it from .whl file. please help.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/catkin_ws/src/duckietown-safe-ml-demo/packages/safe_ml/src/ood_node.py", line 13, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 188, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 141, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libmpi_cxx.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


You have to run this before installing the PyTorch wheel:
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libopenmpi-dev
reference

I have already inserted this line in dockerfile. but still facing same issue.
